# Can not display date as MMM-YY in Power Pivot chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, date, powerpivot

Currently I am working on an excel data model which have several Power Pivot Chart in it. I need to make the date format of the axis become MMM-YY (ex: Mar-19) but can not.

**Current chart format with dd/mm/yyyy format**

[image: IMG:]

The current data type of that column is Date in the data model:

[image: IMG:]

I tried to change the Field setting, but after opening the menu, my menu was quite different from what I saw on the webpage.

**Current Field Setting Menu**

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. What webpage are you referring to in your post? Could you edit your post and include a link to the referenced webpage?

Comment: Maybe you need to refer to "[Change date format on category axis in my PowerPivot column chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648526/change-date-format-on-category-axis-in-my-powerpivot-column-chart)"

Answer (score 0):

Excel handles dates as number of days since 01.01.1900. This means, that an individual date ("dd.mm.yyyy") has an individual integer value. Changing the format to a more general express (e.g. "mm.yyyy") won't change the actual (detailed) integer value behind it.

If you want to generalize your dates, I recommend to add a new column in this Pivot's data source in which you concatenate two date-components 'month' and 'year'. You can easily extract them via the function MONTH() and YEAR(). Afterwards, use this new column index in your PivotTable which will allow the appropriate value aggregation.

(btw: I recommend a format like "yyyymm" since it makes sorting more intuitive)